# How do I determine which code coverage tool was used in Sonarqube analyses?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a large number of Sonarqube projects in a 4.5.4 LTS instance, many of which are conducting Code Coverage analysis.  I want to determine which ones are using Cobertura and which are using JaCoCo (or Clover, or whatever).  The project dashboards do not seem to show this info.  Is the Code Coverage analyzer stored anywhere in the Sonar db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Only the results are stored. To see the coverage tools, you'll have to go back to the jobs that running the analyses; you should be able to tell from the project properties what tool is in use.